# XmlDocument.Load() is freezing, but not receiving any error

Tags: c#, xml, tcp, network-programming, tcplistener

The title pretty much sums up my issue. This application was working pretty perfectly up until recently. Now it is just hanging on the `doc.Load(stream)` line when debugging. There is never an error thrown (waited about 5 minutes), it just sits. Any ideas what the issue could be?

### Listener

```
private void ReceivePortMessages()
{
    string debug = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        Debug.Print(" >> Starting Server");
        IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        _TcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, TcpPort); ;
        Debug.Print(string.Format("{0}:{1}", ipAddress.ToString(), TcpPort.ToString()));
        _TcpListener.Start();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        do
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.Print(" >> Accept connection from client");
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                var tcpClient = _TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                using (var stream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    doc.Load(stream);
                    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
                    string rootName = root.Name;
                    RouteInboundXML(rootName, doc.InnerXml, sw);
                    sw.Restart();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print("ReceivePortMessages: " + ex.ToString());
                _TcpClient.Close();
                _TcpListener.Stop();
                ErrorLog.Write("XmlProcessing", ex.ToString() + "\r\n" + "DataFromClient: " + debug, "ReceivePortMessages()");
                return;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

### Send

```
try
{
    NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input + "\0");
    networkStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    networkStream.Flush();
    byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
    networkStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)client.ReceiveBufferSize);
    string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
    Textbox_FauxXMLReceive.Text += (returndata) + "\n";
    _requestCount++;
    lblRequestCount.Text = string.Format("Request Count: {0}", _requestCount.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Send Message Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    CloseConnection(client);
}
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but I would recommend you to use the newer `XDocument` related classes instead of `XmlDocument`, they are much more comfortable to work with.

Comment: @3dGrabber I don't really have any issues with the xml portion, it's the loading part. It seems more related to the network than anything, but I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Possibly related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6992270a-e94b-47f2-ace9-bf3ef874cab4/xmldocumentloadstream-does-not-return?forum=xmlandnetfx -> http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html